# Checkbox approval

Tags: android, button, checkbox

I want a checkbox to be checked before they can continue to go to the next page (XML). It is working seperate but not together. In the sence that if I push the play button without a checked checkbox, it should only show the toast.
This is what I got.

XML checkbox has itemClicked aas onClick method
    Button has startNewActivity as onClick method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void itemClicked (View v) {
    final Button play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    CheckBox Approved = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Approved);
    Approved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                play.setEnabled(true);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Approve!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void startNewActivity (View view){
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String Name = (String) edit.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, GameSetUp.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", Name);

    itemClicked(view);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Please can you tell what I am doing wrong.

Gr. Jeroen

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that you shouldn't disable play button at all. Try like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    CheckBox Approved = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Approved);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Approved.isSelected()) {
                startNewActivity();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Approve!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void itemClicked(View v) {
    // This method can be removed
}
```

Comment: Hi ehehhh, your code doesnt do the trick. It shows the Toast, but doesn t go to the next page.

Comment: EDIT: Dileep Patel's answer should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ehehhh's answer,

The `OnCheckedChangeListener` will be used to control the play button. You have mistaken the logic of your `startNewActivity` method. Remove the call to `itemClicked` from `startNewActivity`. Instead, put it like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    CheckBox Approved = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Approved);
    Approved.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            play.setEnabled(isChecked);
        }
    });
}

public void startNewActivity(View view)
{
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String Name = (String) edit.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameSetUp.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", Name);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Also, read more about naming conventions for Android, both JAVA and XML :)

Comment: Thanx SlashG I will surely do.

Comment: Hi SlashG, I tried your code. But the startbutton keeps on working allthough the checkbox is not checked!

Comment: This code doesn't disable the `Button` by default. Set that in the XML, or in the `onCreate()` method like this: `play.setEnabled(Approved.isChecked())`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this code hope this can help you..

```
  Button play;
CheckBox Approved;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    Approved = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Approved);
}

public void startNewActivity(View view) {
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String Name = (String) edit.getText().toString();
    if (Approved.isChecked()) {
        play.setEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameSetUp.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", Name);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Approve!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Dileep, Much thanx for the code. The awnser was simpler than I thought of.

Comment: @ Jeroen van der Schalie ,welcome if this can help you then please accpet my answer..thanks.